To Change item Name In oracle apex
I want to do this in Oracle Apex!
To change my item name based on value, i have a select list, if i choose 1 then item name will be 'Sale Amt.' else item name will be 'Credit Amt.'
I want to Change item label name based on above condition but i don't know where and how i can use it.

Create a hidden item (let's call it P1_LABEL) and set its value (for example, with a dynamic action when select list item's value changes) to
return case when :P1_SELECT_LIST = 1 then 'Sale Amt.'
            else                          'Credit Amt.'
       end;

Then modify target item's label to &P1_LABEL. (literally & followed by P1_LABEL followed by .) and that's it.

Brother i want to Change its Label name according to the above condition. Kinday share, if you have solution. Thanks

That is the solution.

Your Answer is right but my requirement is different. the code i was shared blow i was want that.

Correct Answer:
Event: Change
Selection Type: item
Item(s) : P1_ITEM
True Action: Execute Javascript Code:
if ($v("P1_CONDITION_ITEM") == 1) {
    $("label[for=P1_ITEM] ").text("Sale Amt");
} else if ($v("P1_CONDITION_ITEM") == 2) {
    $("label[for=P1_ITEM]").text("Credit Amt");
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
